# Subsetting the output data from an API request

Tags: python, typeerror

I am fetching some data from an API with the following code:

```
import requests

url = "http://prognos.konj.se/PxWeb/api/v1/sv/SenastePrognosen/f06_rantorochvaxelkurser/F0604.px"

querystring = {
  "query": [
    {
      "code": "variabel",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "F0604Repo_u"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "code": "period",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "321",
          "322",
          "323",
          "324"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "response": {
    "format": "px"
  }
}

response = requests.post(url, json=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

The print statement yields the following answer (omitting all the output for brevity):

```
LINK[en]="http://www.konj.se/prognosdokumentationpx";
DATA=
-0.2500 -0.2500 -0.2500 0.0000 
;
```

Now I would like to fetch the DATA part only. My first thought was:
print(response["Data"])

yielding the error:

```
TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable
```

Any advice on how to do this, i.e. fetch the Data part of the output?

**EDIT:**
Following @joshmerandas answer yields the error:

```
json = response.json()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-68-45bbb244f888>", line 1, in <module>
    json = response.json()

  File "C:MyUserProfile\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 898, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\C:MyUserProfile\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "C:\Users\C:MyUserProfile\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

  File "C:\Users\C:MyUserProfile\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the json data in the `response` before pulling the data from the returne json. See the documentation for the [`Response`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response) object. You'll find the [`json(**kwargs)`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.json) method. So yo access the `"Data"` field from the json you would whave someting like:

```py
response = requests.post(url, json=querystring)
json = response.json()

data = json["Data"]

print(data)
```

Comment: Using `.json()` raises a `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError`

Comment: See the edit @joshmeranda. No idea why that happends?

Comment: That would be caused by invalid / malformed json data in the response. `Response.json` is essentially just a wrapper around [`josn.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) which raises that error "If the data being deserialized is not a valid JSON document, a JSONDecodeError will be raised."